# Reversing a string, not working

Tags: java, string, methods, reverse

I commented out the options pane to get a quick view of the output..I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I just started a computer science class. My output is the same as the input but I know the reverse string method is correct because I tested it.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class ReverseString
{
  public static void reverse(String n)
  {
    for(int i=0; i<n.length();i++)
    {
      n=n .substring(1, n.length()-i)
      +n.substring(0,1)
      +n.substring(n.length()-i, n.length());
    }
  }

  public static void main (String []arg)
  {
    String n = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Input String to reverse"));
    reverse(n);
    System.out.println(n);
   // JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Reversed String is: "+Input);
  }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?
Also you need to access your reverse function through your class name
`ReverseString.reverse(n);`

Comment: This is working fine!

Comment: @LJ_1102 The class name isn't necessary as the methods are part of the same class, however some will tell you it is a best practice.

Comment: If I input "REVERSE" into the dialog box I get "REVERSE" as my string instead of "ESREVER"

Comment: @LINEMAN78 you're right, i though the class was defined over the `main` definition, indention fail...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. But I use it all the time for quick, beginner questions I have

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome I posted my answer lemme how it went

Comment: It works. I appreciate the help everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static void reverse(String n)
```

your return type is `void` so this function does not return anything , so you will not have any reverse 
in your console.

why you get the same result?
because you just print it out by following line

```
System.out.println(n); <-- you did not pass this n into your function.
                           Even though if you did, nothing would happened because 
                           your reverse return type is void
```

if you add `System.out.println(n);` after your for loop, your code works fine.

```
 public static void reverse(String n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length(); i++) {
            n = n.substring(1, n.length() - i)
                    + n.substring(0, 1)
                    + n.substring(n.length() - i, n.length());
        }
        System.out.println(n); <---- print out the reverse result on the console
                                     from the reverse function 
    }
```

[Read More About Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: Also, an easier method for reversing a string is `new StringBuilder(n).reverse().toString()`. The method currently used pollutes the string pool (don't expect a beginner to know this, but something all Java devs should eventually learn)

Comment: @LINEMAN78 I totally agree, but lets not to confuse the op more than he or she is :)

Comment: Yessss!! You're amazing!  Now I just need a dialog box that displays the new string without the input bar of the joptionspane..

Comment: The conditons are that I can only use the .toString method and string.length method

Comment: <3 I appreciate you guys

Comment: public static String reverse(String n)   returning n and using it in main.

Comment: what ? if you have more question, please ask different question, so everybody can help you.

Comment: @KickButtowski Agreed, however something I like to point out as even a lot of professional Java devs don't realize this since the protection added in the 1.5 compiler (which does no good when appending strings in a loop).

Comment: IF I  were to change void to String and return n.. how would I be able to get that reversed String in my main method?

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome You need to store the result of the reverse message back into n. `n = reverse(n)`. The original 'n' object is not modified as Strings are immutable and Java is pass by value (sort of, more accurately object references are passed by value).